# PHP - using curl, is it possible to transfer a variable from curled address to current?

Tags: php, curl

Say I'm curling to a php file i.e. www.example.com/example.php, and there's a variable within example.php named $example that I want saved in the current file i am using to curl. is there any way to do this? I've tried a couple solutions like sessions / get, but none are working for me.

Comment: When you access a PHP script through a webserver, the script is executed, you don't get the source code. There's no way to get variables.

Answer (score -1):

put the variable in a response header? know that the values you can put in a header is very limited, thus you should probably base64_encode it first, for example, newlines, questionmarks, etc, are not allowed. alternatively, assuming both files use the same session backend, you could transfer the variables through $_SESSION (first your file calls `session_start();$_SESSION['var']=whatever;$id=session_id();session_write_close();` , then set the cookie session through CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER like `"Cookie: PHPSESSID=".$id;` , then your example.php calls `session_start();$var=$_SESSION['var'];$_SESSION['var2']=whatever2;session_write_close();`, then when curl_exec has finished, call `session_start($id);$var2=$_SESSION['var2'];` - congratulations, you have just transferred 2 variables between the 2 files, $_SESSION['var'] and $_SESSION['var2'];